# inherit @RestController on spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have parent class decorate with @RestController annotation, when child class inherit parent class without @RestController, child class methods don't expose as a rest service. i use spring boot and want create parent class for all of my child controller. any solution?

Comment: The `@RestController` like all other derived `@Component` annotations aren't inherited. You will have the explicitly annotate all your controller.s